# Emgu.CV Fisheye.Calibrate method

Tags: c#, emgucv, camera-calibration, fisheye

I'm currently trying to use the Fisheye.Calibrate method and the Fisheye.UndistorImage method from the Emgu.CV library. As far as I've understood, the Calibrate method is used to calculate a camera matrix (K) and a distortion vector (D), which are to be used to undistort fisheye-images using the UndistorImage method. However, when I use these two methods the results are not convincing. This is the input image I'm testing on: [fisheye input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAAyb.png) and this is the result: [fisheye output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPbyc.png).

When I tried to look at the values of K and D by looking at the data-variable of the objects, it said 'null' for both K and D. Therefore I'm unsure if I'm using the Calibrate() metod correctly. My code is as follow:

```
private void EmguCVUndistortFisheye()
    {
        string[] fileNames = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Test\Desktop\Jakob\ImageAnalysis\Images\Calibration", "*.png");
        Size patternSize = new Size(6, 8);
        VectorOfVectorOfPoint3D32F objPoints = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint3D32F();
        VectorOfVectorOfPointF imagePoints = new VectorOfVectorOfPointF();
        foreach (string file in fileNames)
        {
            Mat img = CvInvoke.Imread(file, ImreadModes.Grayscale);
            CvInvoke.Imshow("input", img);
            VectorOfPointF corners = new VectorOfPointF(patternSize.Width * patternSize.Height);
            bool find = CvInvoke.FindChessboardCorners(img, patternSize, corners);
            if (find)
            {
                MCvPoint3D32f[] points = new MCvPoint3D32f[patternSize.Width * patternSize.Height];
                int loopIndex = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < patternSize.Height; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < patternSize.Width; j++)
                        points[loopIndex++] = new MCvPoint3D32f(j, i, 0);
                }
                objPoints.Push(new VectorOfPoint3D32F(points));
                imagePoints.Push(corners);
            }
        }
        Size imageSize = new Size(1280, 1024);
        Mat K = new Mat();
        Mat D = new Mat();
        Mat rotation = new Mat();
        Mat translation = new Mat();
        Fisheye.Calibrate(
            objPoints,
            imagePoints,
            imageSize,
            K,
            D,
            rotation,
            translation,
            Fisheye.CalibrationFlag.CheckCond,
            new MCvTermCriteria(30, 0.1)
        );

        foreach (string file in fileNames)
        {
            Mat img = CvInvoke.Imread(file, ImreadModes.Grayscale);
            Mat output = img.Clone();
            Fisheye.UndistorImage(img, output, K, D);
            CvInvoke.Imshow("output", output);
        }
    }
```

Is the reason for my strange results a consequence of wrong parameters to the Calibrate method or is it simply the case of not using enough input images?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a similar problem to one I had recently when trying to pass a `Mat` into the calibration function when it needed a `Matrix` and as you've found it just doesn't work without reporting any errors. I think you'll need the following:

```
var K = new Matrix<double>(3, 3);
var D = new Matrix<double>(4, 1);
```

Also note that if you want to retrieve the rotation and translation vectors passing a `Mat` in is fine but you'll probably want to convert back to a `Matrix` if you want to perform calculations on them. I was just using a normal camera calibration rather than fish-eye but the following working code fragment might be useful to get the idea:

```
var cameraMatrix = new Matrix<double>(3, 3);
var distortionCoeffs = new Matrix<double>(4, 1);
var termCriteria = new MCvTermCriteria(30, 0.1);
System.Drawing.PointF[][] imagePoints = imagePointsList.Select(p => p.ToArray()).ToArray();
MCvPoint3D32f[][] worldPoints = worldPointsList.Select(p => p.ToArray()).ToArray();
double error = CvInvoke.CalibrateCamera(worldPoints, imagePoints, imageSize, cameraMatrix, distortionCoeffs, CalibType.RationalModel, termCriteria, out Mat[] rotationVectors, out Mat[] translationVectors);
var rotation = new Matrix<double>(rotationVectors[0].Rows, rotationVectors[0].Cols, rotationVectors[0].DataPointer);
var translation = new Matrix<double>(translationVectors[0].Rows, translationVectors[0].Cols, translationVectors[0].DataPointer);
```